# Making Zuul Api Gateway highly available using load balancer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am planning to use zuul API gateway as an entry point for my microservices.
A Web and mobile client will connect to API gateway. Now I have a doubt and need some suggestions, how should I make API gateway highly available. Should I use a load balancer (server-side load balancer) in front of multiple instances of API gateway? The server-side load balancer will select the API gateway in round robin fashion.

Comment: yes, zuul is stateless

Comment: Zuul is a JVM-based router and server-side load balancer from Netflix.